# jQuery/JavaScript on click, list ID's names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, jquery-selectors

First off, my javascript is very limited so I wont try anything on my own on this one as I just cant think where to start

So, I have this structure in my website,

```css
ul{list-style-type: none;padding:0}
```

```html
<button class="clickme" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<ul>
 
    <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" class="color_input" value="ffffff"></li>
    <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" class="color_input" value="000000"></li>
    <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" class="color_input" value="575757"></li>
    
    <!--There will be at least 30-40 of elements like this that contains text input tags-->
    
    <!--And, this list arent always have Text inputs tags, there are also other tags for example, radio, select...etc-->
    <!-- <li id="radio-toggle"><input type="radio" class="radio_input" value="toggle"></li> -->
</ul>

<div class="list">

</div>
```

Basically, A bunch of `li` tags that each one have a specific `ID` and each of this list contains a text `input` tag that they have a class named `color_input`

So, With jQuery on clicking the `clickme` button I want to list all `li` ID **names** with their input **values** in a div
For example, on clicking the `clickme` button I want to get a list like this

```
'colors_body' => 'ffffff',  
'colors_wrapper' => '000000',  
'colors_footer' => '575757',
```

**EDIT:** But I need to get a list that the text input tags used for colors only, this should be easy to map the list because this input tags have a specfic class named `color_input`
The reason for that because there are other input types like radio, select...etc

Comment: Do you want just those three?  Are there going to be more?  I'm missing what part of this is dynamic that would constitute "finding all" of them, instead of just looking for those three.  Otherwise, stick a class on them, and find them all by that class.

Comment: Hello, Yes, there will be at least 40-50 elements like this :) the ID's starts with colors_ :) so i think this should be fine to find with something like [id^='colors_']  right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, doing this with jQuery is a piece of cake.

you need to catch clicks on the element `.clickme` like this:

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
});
```

Inside that, use a jQuery `.each()` loop to perform a function on each and every `li`, the id of which starting with `colors_`:

```
  $('li[id^="colors_"]').each(function() {
  });
```

and inside that, get the id and text of the element, and do whatever you want with it (in this instance I've `console.log`ged it)

```
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + " => " + $(this).children('input[type=text]').val());
```

```js
$('.clickme').click(function() {
  $('li[id^="colors_"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')+" => "+$(this).children('input[type=text]').val());
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickme" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<ul>
  <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" value="ffffff"></li>
  <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" value="000000"></li>
  <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" value="575757"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Your answer is exactly what i was looking for :) Thank you.

Comment: oops, was just a mistake to be honest haha i edited my post alot, but all good now, Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You should attach event click to the `clickme` button like :

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
  //Your logic here
});
```

Then loop through all the `li`'s using `each()` method and asign the values to the `div` using jQuery method `append()` :

```
$('div').append( $(this).attr('id') + ' => ' + $('input', this).val() + '<br/>' );
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
  $('ul li').each(function(){
     $('div').append( $(this).attr('id')+' => '+$('input', this).val()+'<br/>' );
  })
});
```

```css
ul{list-style-type: none;padding:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickme" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<ul>
 
    <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" value="ffffff"></li>
    <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" value="000000"></li>
    <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" value="575757"></li>
    
</ul>

<div class="list">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JS: `Array.prototype.forEach` on the list-items we can do this.

```js
document.querySelector(".clickme").addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  var div = document.querySelector("div.list");
  //Iterate over every li
  Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll("ul > li[id^='color_']"), function(element){
    var node = document.createTextNode(element.id + " => " + element.querySelector("input").value);
    div.appendChild(node);
    div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  });
  
}, true);// assign click handler to button
```

```css
ul{list-style-type: none;padding:0}
```

```html
<button class="clickme" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<ul>
 
    <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" value="ffffff"></li>
    <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" value="000000"></li>
    <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" value="575757"></li>
    
</ul>

<div class="list">

</div>
```

Comment: I think jQuery is like Apple. It's shorter and takes work out of your hands but if you start with it, getting the inner workings of JavaScript is difficult. So if an OP asks for pure JS, it's better to answer in pure (or both). The difference in answers here serves both options.

Answer (score 1):

Create an *object* with the map that is required first and then append it to the `list` - see demo below:

**jQuery** solution:

```js
$('.clickme').click(function() {
  $('ul li').map(function() {
    return {
      name: this.id,
      value: $(this).find('input').val()
    }
  }).get().forEach(function(e) {
    $('.list').append('<div>' + e.name + ' => ' + e.value + '</div>');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {list-style-type: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickme" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<ul>
  <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" value="ffffff"></li>
  <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" value="000000"></li>
  <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" value="575757"></li>
</ul>

<div class="list"></div>
```

**Javascript** solution:

```js
document.querySelector('.clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(e) {
    return {
      name: e.id,
      value: e.querySelector('input').value
    }
  }).forEach(function(e) {
  
    document.querySelector('.list').innerHTML += '<div>' + e.name + ' => ' + e.value + '</div>';
  });
});
```

```css
ul {list-style-type: none;}
```

```html
<button class="clickme" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<ul>
  <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" value="ffffff"></li>
  <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" value="000000"></li>
  <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" value="575757"></li>
</ul>

<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll` & `children` to get the relevant data.

```js
document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inputText = "";
  var obj = {};
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(item) {
    inputText += item.id + ' ' + item.children[0].value + '<br/>'

  })
  document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0].innerHTML = inputText


})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="clickme" type="button" id="clickMe">Click Me!</button>

<ul>

  <li id="colors_body"><input type="text" value="ffffff"></li>
  <li id="colors_wrapper"><input type="text" value="000000"></li>
  <li id="colors_footer"><input type="text" value="575757"></li>

</ul>

<div class="list">

</div>
```